# openssl EVP fails randomly in decryption

Tags: c++, c, encryption, openssl

I have a problem in using higher level envelope decryption fron `openssl/evp.h` 
`EVP_OpenFinal` and `EVP_OpenInit` fail randomly when I try to run the same program multiple times with the same values. I am working on it for last 5 days but no luck. I am writing my complete code here. Please help me out. It would be very nice if someone can try to reproduce the errors, and let me know where I am wrong.

Error message:

```
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
4944:error:0606506D:lib(6):func(101):reason(109):.\crypto\evp\evp_enc.c:460:
```

And here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void handleErrors(void);
int envelope_seal(EVP_PKEY **pub_key, unsigned char *plaintext, int plaintext_len,
                  unsigned char **encrypted_key, int *encrypted_key_len, unsigned char *iv,
                  unsigned char *ciphertext);
int envelope_open(EVP_PKEY *priv_key, unsigned char *ciphertext, int ciphertext_len,
                  unsigned char *encrypted_key, int encrypted_key_len, unsigned char *iv,
                  unsigned char *plaintext);

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    RSA *rsa_pubkey= RSA_new();
    RSA *rsa_prikey= RSA_new();
    EVP_PKEY *evp_pubkey = EVP_PKEY_new();
    EVP_PKEY *evp_prikey = EVP_PKEY_new();
    FILE *rsa_prikey_file = NULL;
    FILE *rsa_pubkey_file = NULL;
    rsa_pubkey_file = fopen("pubkey.pem", "r");
    if (!rsa_pubkey_file)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error loading PEM RSA Public Key File.\n");
        exit(2);
    }

    PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY(rsa_pubkey_file, &rsa_pubkey,NULL, NULL);

    EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(evp_pubkey,rsa_pubkey);

    rsa_prikey_file = fopen("key.pem", "r");
    if (!rsa_prikey_file)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error loading PEM RSA private Key File.\n");
        exit(2);
    }
    PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(rsa_prikey_file, &rsa_prikey,NULL, NULL);

    EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(evp_prikey,rsa_prikey);


    unsigned char *plaintext = (unsigned char*) "The quick brown fox jumps over thes lazy dog";
    unsigned char ciphertext[256] = {};
    unsigned char plaintextt[256] = {};
    int ciphertextlength;
    unsigned char *encKey  = (unsigned char*)malloc(RSA_size(rsa_pubkey));
    unsigned char iv[16] = {};


    envelope_seal(&evp_pubkey, plaintext,strlen((const char*)plaintext),&encKey, &ciphertextlength,iv,ciphertext);

    envelope_open(evp_prikey, ciphertext, strlen((const char*)ciphertext), encKey, strlen((const char*)encKey),iv,plaintextt);

    std::cout <<"Result: "<<plaintextt<<std::endl;

    EVP_PKEY_free(evp_pubkey);
    EVP_PKEY_free(evp_prikey);
    free(ciphertext);
    free(encKey);

}

int envelope_seal(EVP_PKEY **pub_key, unsigned char *plaintext, int plaintext_len,
                  unsigned char **encrypted_key, int *encrypted_key_len, unsigned char *iv,
                  unsigned char *ciphertext)
{
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;

    int ciphertext_len;

    int len;

    if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new())) handleErrors();

    if(1 != EVP_SealInit(ctx, EVP_aes_128_cbc(),
                         encrypted_key,
                         encrypted_key_len,
                         iv,
                         pub_key, 1))
    {
        handleErrors();
    }

    if(1 != EVP_SealUpdate(ctx, ciphertext, &len, plaintext, plaintext_len))
    {
        handleErrors();
    }
    ciphertext_len = len;

    if(1 != EVP_SealFinal(ctx, ciphertext + len, &len))
    {
        handleErrors();
    }
    ciphertext_len += len;

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);

    return ciphertext_len;
}



int envelope_open(EVP_PKEY *priv_key, unsigned char *ciphertext, int ciphertext_len,
                  unsigned char *encrypted_key, int encrypted_key_len, unsigned char *iv,
                  unsigned char *plaintext)
{
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;

    int len;

    int plaintext_len;

    if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new()))
    {
        handleErrors();
    }

    if(1 != EVP_OpenInit(ctx, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), encrypted_key,
                         encrypted_key_len, iv, priv_key))
    {
        handleErrors();
    }

    if(1 != EVP_OpenUpdate(ctx, plaintext, &len, ciphertext, ciphertext_len))
    {
        handleErrors();
    }
    plaintext_len = len;

    if(1 != EVP_OpenFinal(ctx, plaintext + len, &len))
    {
        handleErrors();
    }
    plaintext_len += len;

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
    plaintext[plaintext_len] = '\0';

    return plaintext_len;
}


void handleErrors(void)
{
    perror("Error: ");
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    abort();
}
```

Comment: EVP_OpenInit() returns 0 on error or a non zero integer (actually the recovered secret key size) if successful.

Comment: Okay, but why random failures with the same data?

Comment: You're ignoring return values. Start checking for failures from functions like `PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY` and `PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey`. And call `RSA_check_key` to validate the keys you are loading.

Comment: I believe ***`strlen((const char*)ciphertext)`*** is one of your problems. You may have others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`envelope_seal()` gives back the length of the encrypted string, I have to put this length in `envelope_open()`

```
int **length** = envelope_seal(&evp_pubkey, plaintext,strlen((const char*)plaintext),&encKey, &ciphertextlength,iv,ciphertext);
envelope_open(evp_prikey, ciphertext, **length**, encKey, strlen((const char*)encKey),iv,plaintextt);
```

Answer (score 2):

The random crashing is caused by your length calculations before `envelope_seal` and `envelope_open`. The lengths should look like:

```
unsigned char *plaintext = (unsigned char*) "The quick brown fox jumps over thes lazy dog";
int ciphertextlength;
unsigned int enclen = EVP_PKEY_size(evp_prikey);
unsigned char *encKey  = (unsigned char*)malloc(enclen);
unsigned char *ciphertext = (unsigned char*)malloc(enclen);
unsigned char plaintextt[enclen] = {};
unsigned char iv[16] = {};


unsigned int length = envelope_seal(&evp_pubkey, plaintext,strlen((const char*)plaintext),&encKey, &ciphertextlength,iv,ciphertext);
envelope_open(evp_prikey, ciphertext, length, encKey, enclen,iv,plaintextt);
```

As your answer states `envelope_seal` returns the size. You cannot get the size of a `char*` as your crashing always occured when the size of your `plaintext` was less than `48`.